# How do I get (a, b) => c from a => b => c in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, currying

If I have:

```
val f : A => B => C
```

This is shorthand for:

```
val f : Function1[A, Function1[B, C]]
```

How do I get a function `g` with the signature:

```
val g : (A, B) => C = error("todo")
```

(i.e.)

```
val g : Function2[A, B, C] //or possibly
val g : Function1[(A, B), C]
```

in terms of `f`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
scala> val f : Int => Int => Int = a => b => a + b
f: (Int) => (Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> Function.uncurried(f)
res0: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

Comment: Odd that there is no `uncurried` method on `FunctionN` itself?

Comment: To have an uncurried method on Function1, you would need to limit the acceptable targets of it to functions that return functions.  That is to say functions with type Function1[A, Function1[B, C]].  That could probably be done with generalized type constraints, but those weren't available until Scala 2.8.

Answer (score 15):

Extending retonym's answer, for completeness

```
val f : Int => Int => Int = a => b => a + b
val g: (Int, Int) => Int = Function.uncurried(f)
val h: ((Int, Int)) => Int = Function.tupled(g)
```

The converse functions for both of these operations are also provided on the Function object, so you could write the above backwards, if you wished

```
val h: ((Int, Int)) => Int =  x =>(x._1 + x._2)
val g: (Int, Int) => Int = Function.untupled(h)
val f : Int => Int => Int = g.curried  //Function.curried(g) would also work, but is deprecated. Wierd
```

Answer (score 11):

Just to round out the answer, although there is a library method to do this, it may also be instructive to do it by hand:

```
scala> val f = (i: Int) => ((s: String) => i*s.length)
f: (Int) => (String) => Int = <function1>

scala> val g = (i: Int, s: String) => f(i)(s)
g: (Int, String) => Int = <function2>
```

Or in general,

```
def uncurry[A,B,C](f: A=>B=>C): (A,B)=>C = {
  (a: A, b: B) => f(a)(b)
}
```

Comment: def uncurry[A,B,C](f: A=>B=>C): (A,B)=>C = {
  (a, b) => f(a)(b)
} //You can omit the type

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer by Rex Kerr but easier to read.

```
type A = String
type B = Int
type C = Boolean

val f: A => B => C = s => i => s.toInt+i > 10

val f1: (A, B) => C = f(_)(_)
```